# What is the reason for passing SyntaxKind to factory methods of class Syntax?

Tags: c#, roslyn

In Roslyn CTP the following signature of methods is used quite commonly:

```
LiteralExpressionSyntax LiteralExpression(SyntaxKind kind, SyntaxToken token)
```

What is the reason for passing SyntaxKind? `token` itself has `Kind` property, why Roslyn do not use it?

To be more precise, it takes user-provided `kind`, asserts that it is limited to a narrow set of values, then checks that `token`'s `Kind` also belongs to this narrow set, and then passes user-provided `kind` further.

Why Roslyn not uses `token.Kind` and makes user to pass explicit kind?

UPD: Actually, the main question is: what are situations when `kind`, passed by user, will be different than `token`'s kind?

Comment: Are their other subclasses of kind?

Comment: kind is a huge enum with all kind of syntax kinds, like `StringLiteralExpression` and so on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look closely, you'll see that the kinds checked are **not** actually the same in each case.  There are separate `SyntaxKinds` for and expressions - so you would have a `SyntaxKind.TrueKeyword` for the token, and `SyntaxKind.TrueLiteralExpression` for the resulting `LiteralExpressionSyntax`.  To answer your updated question, the resulting `expression.Kind` will **never** match the `token.Kind`.

However, it does appear to be the case that there is a one-to-one correspondence of token kinds to expression kinds in this case, which means we could derive the expression kind from the token kind.  I'll raise this internally.

Comment: I wonder what is the semantic difference between `SyntaxKind.TrueKeyword` and `TrueLiteralExpression`.

Comment: One represents a token, or terminal in the grammar, and the other a SyntaxNode or non-terminal in the grammar.  We had a design goal that we wouldn't conflate meaning between the two.

Comment: @MikhailBrinchuk The `true` keyword does not necessary represent a literal of type `bool`. For example, it can be part of a declaration of a user-defined operator `public static bool operator true(...)`.